# RK1 service insulator

Tags: electrical, wire

I was told by the electrical inspector that I needed to install a RK1 insulator. I have looked everywhere and I find a myriad of devices that look similar to what he described, but nothing explicitly called "RK1".....can anyone point me in the right direction please???

Comment: Well.....as soon as I posted I found this:https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-16-in-x-3-in-Service-Entrance-SE-Clevis-60625/202077080

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question here should you be so inclined.

Comment: I'm still not sure if this is what the inspector was talking about. I'm upgrading from 100 to 200amp service at my house......from main panel and meter base up to the weatherhead if that info helps.

Comment: ??? RK1 is a fuse type. Maybe you should contact him and ask for a clarification. Is he asking you to install a main fuse switch?

Comment: No.....I might have written it down wrong or he misspoke......but I confirmed with him that he was referencing a clevis insulator like the one I linked to in my comment above